# PHP deep inside HTML tags and attributes

Tags: php, html

I've come across a situation where there's a gnarly mix of HTML and PHP (well at least it seems that way to me because I'm not an expert in PHP).  Currently, there's a hard-coded URL that I'd like to generalize using a PHP function.  However, this is where I'm running into issues as this mix is getting rather complex.

After spending over 2 hours on this, I think I'm at a point where looking through topics on this doesn't seem to discuss this particular use case, and lots of trial-and-error isn't yielding the desired results.

Inside my template, I have the following code for my sidebar:

```
<h4>About <?php the_title(); ?> </h4>
<div id="about-this-waterfall-acf">
    <?php
        // First attempt HTML in PHP
        $home_url = get_home_url();
        echo '<div class="field-title"><a class="field-value rating" target="_blank" href=' . $home_url . '/rating-criteria/' . '>Rating:</a> <span class="rating">' . the_field('rating') . '</span></div>'; ?>
        // Second attempt PHP in HTML
        <div class="field-title"><a class="field-value rating" target="_blank" href="<$php $homeurl = get_home_url(); echo $homeurl; ?>/rating-criteria">Rating:</a> <span class="rating"><?php the_field('rating'); ?></span></div>
        // The hard-coded URL that I'm trying to generalize
        <div class="field-title"><a class="field-value difficulty" target="_blank" href="https://s1.temporary-access.com/~allacros/sandbox2/difficulty-criteria/">Difficulty:</a> <span class="difficulty"><?php the_field('difficulty'); ?></span></div>
```

...

The results of this code can be seen in the sidebar in:
https://s1.temporary-access.com/~allacros/sandbox2/california-switzer-falls.html

In that sidebar (beneath "About Switzer Falls" below the Hero Image), you can see 2 Ratings.
The first one has the correct link, but the formatting is off as the "2" is not where it's supposed to be and it's unformatted.
The second one has the correct formatting, but it has the incorrect link.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: in your second link, you used `<$php` instead of `<?php` and, you just need to `echo $homeurl;`, also, instead of ending abrupty, you can append the `/rating-...` to the `$homeurl`

Comment: Thank you very much.  That fixed the link.  Amazing how a little character like that throws everything off.

Answer (score 0):

For the first line, looks like there is "echo" statement in your function the_field("rating"), which cause the rating "2" output first before your "echo" execute.

For the second line, there is error at "$php", which should be "?php".

Answer (score 0):

Change your 2nd statement to the following:

```
<div class="field-title"><a class="field-value rating" target="_blank" href="<$php $homeurl = get_home_url(); echo $homeurl; ?>/rating-criteria">Rating:</a> <span class="rating"><?php echo the_field('rating'); ?></span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others have mentioned about the $ where a ? should be, you could maybe even simplify things for yourself by doing something like this for the link. All you've got to do is echo the $home_url variable you're creating at the start.

```
<a href ="<?php echo $home_url . '/rating-criteria' ?>">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, really. There's a number of things you are doing on one single line that you don't actually need to do...

```
<h4>About <?php the_title(); ?> </h4>
<div id="about-this-waterfall-acf">
    <div class="field-title">
        <a class="field-value rating" target="_blank" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/rating-criteria/">Rating:</a>
        <span class="rating"><?php the_field('rating'); ?></span>
    </div>
```

Now, things to note... I split the HTML over multiple lines instead of trying to keep it on just one. I have also removed the bulk of it from PHP processing altogether, as the static HTML doesn't need to go through PHP. This cleans it up immensely.

Lastly, if you look back at your code, you were echoing out the return value of the_field. This is where your random '2' is coming from, most likely. the_field should be outputting the value itself, so you should not concatenate it's return value on then output it.